# How to run a Batch file on a file share on Windows 2008 from an HTML web site using the onload event

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2010, vbscript

I need to run a batch file on a file share and need to run it when a user navigate to the http://www.test.com link.  Using the Onload event will make the execution automatic and will run whe the page loads.

Is this possible?

On IE 11
Windows 2008 R2

Thank you,
Rad

Comment: Do you want to run the batch file from the client or from the (web)server?

Answer (score 1):

SQL SERVER can run batch files... maybe your web can call a store procedure to run the batch file

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/27/sql-server-running-batch-file-using-t-sql-xp_cmdshell-bat-file/

```
DECLARE @PassedVariable VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)
SET @PassedVariable = 'SqlAuthority.com'
SET @CMDSQL = 'c:findword.bat' + @PassedVariable
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell @CMDSQL
```

Comment: Wen the Web page loads, Onload even needs to run the batch file to run the log update.